# Windows 10 and WSL - Directories not appearing in Bash when created in File Explorer

Tags: bash, windows-10, file-permissions, windows-explorer, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using Windows 10 Enterprise Insider Preview Buil 14372.rs1_release.160620-2342

When I create a directory in Bash (e.g. `mkdir test_from_bash`) it appears in the File Explorer but the opposite doesn't work. File Explorer -> New Folder (call it 'test_from_gui') then running `ls -al` in Bash does not show the new directory.

I don't think this is a permissions problem since I went into the Properties -> Security section for each directory using the File Explorer and both of the aforementioned directories both have every box checked except for 'Special permissions' at the bottom of the list.

Result from `ls -al`:

[image]

File explorer:

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: That's nuts! Is that a networked drive? In that case, can you try on a local windows drive?

Comment: Ah maybe you're onto something? This is Windows on Parallels (on my mac)

Comment: can you try to create a file using explorer too? and can you test on a local drive like on your temporary drive ($TEMP / %TEMP%)

Comment: I made a file under C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\tmp (not sure of the directory/container structure but looks like all the Ubuntu stuff is under 'lxss') using Explorer and it didn't show up in Bash. The opposite worked though (`touch /tmp/file_from_bash`) so it looks like the same issue

Comment: Can you try on a windows known path? like `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp` ? You mean you're running windows on a Virtual Machine?

Comment: From within bash, there is no way that I know of to access directories outside of lxss. Both the bash root directory and bash user home directory are within the lxss directory.

Comment: Just cd the windows path within double quotes.

Comment: I think this is intended behaviour as discussed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/51#issuecomment-210544384).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Workaround -

Create and work out of directories that are outside of the Ubuntu 'container', you can find them in the `/mnt` directory. For example, you can happily read/write/modify/delete files from `C:\Users` in Windows Explorer (or `cmd` or anywhere else in Windows land) and also do the same from Bash but those files will be located in `/mnt/c/Users`. Not perfect, though, and I'd love to see a better answer.

Comment: Great advice, but I would say "Supported method that will not corrupt your Linux subsystem" rather than "Workaround", wrt https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/